# I want to know about where "c" file generate after making GUI in Glide

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

i am using GTK3.0 library and Glade tool to build GUI using "c". can anyone tell me that after making GUI in Glade where actually "c" file generate.??

Comment: Did you mean Glade? Glade doesn't generate C an application must load it.

Answer (score 0):

Glade doesn't generate code anymore. Old versions did, but the resulting code was unmaintable as you needed to edit the code generated, making it hard to change the UI afterwards.

Nowaday, you just use the GtkBuilder class to load the GUI description, as stated in the documentation.

```
/* Construct a GtkBuilder instance and load our UI description */
builder = gtk_builder_new ();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.ui", NULL);

/* Connect signal handlers to the constructed widgets. */
window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
```

Source: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html (official documentation)